# Confusion about bind & call in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, call, bind, slice

When I'm reading Array.prototype.slice in MDN, I found an example: [Array-like objects:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice#Array-like)

Here is the sample code:

```
var unboundSlice = Array.prototype.slice;
var boundSlice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);

function list() {
  return boundSlice(arguments, 0);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]
```

What's the function call process when call `list(1, 2, 3)`?

1. I know that in `list()`, it calls `boundSlice([1, 2, 3], 0)`. But what happened in `boundSlice`?
2. I understand that `boundSlice` is a bound function to the `call()` function of `Function.prototype`, with the `this` value set to the `slice()` function of `Array.prototype`.
3. `slice()` is the `this`, then how to produce result `[1, 2, 3]`? I guess the final call is `[1, 2, 3].slice(0)`, am I right? If I'm right, how could this happen, can anyone explain the inner process to me?

Comment: It's basically saying `Array.prototype.slice.call( [1, 2, 3] , 0 );`  to understand that, you should look more into 'call' and 'bind'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var boundSlice = Function.prototype.call.bind(unboundSlice);
```

This is basically:

```
var boundSlice = function (thisArg, arg1) {
    unboundSlice.call(thisArg, arg1);
};
```

The tricky part is how does it know to execute the `call` operation on `unboundSlice`? That's because the `call` method uses the `this` value internally to know which function to invoke and since we set the `this` value to `unboundSlice` by using `...call.bind(unboundSlice)` it invokes this method.

For example, when we do `Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)`, the `this` value inside `call` will be `Array.prototype.slice` since the `this` value is always the left side of the `.` when not altered.

You assumptions were right about the result of `list(1, 2, 3)` being `[1, 2, 3].slice(0)`.

Note that `list` can simply be implemented as:

```
function list() {
    return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
    //or return [].slice.call(arguments);
}
```